How to get data from json sub array with PHP
I want to get, for example, the data of name of the Origin or Destination and echo it with php.
(json file not complete, just the start of it)
json file:
Array
(
    [Trip] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [ServiceDays] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [planningPeriodBegin] => 2024-05-14
                                    [planningPeriodEnd] => 2024-09-26
                                    [sDaysR] => inte varje dag
                                    [sDaysI] => 13. t o m 16. aug 2024
                                    [sDaysB] => 00000000007CF9F3E7CF9F3E0000000000
                                )

                        )

                    [LegList] => Array
                        (
                            [Leg] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [Origin] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [name] => Rådhuset
                                                    [type] => ST
                                                    [id] => A=1@O=Rådhuset@X=18044092@Y=59330729@U=74@L=400110557@
                                                    [extId] => 400110557
                                                    [lon] => 18.044092
                                                    [lat] => 59.330729
                                                    [prognosisType] => PROGNOSED
                                                    [time] => 20:46:00
                                                    [date] => 2024-08-13
                                                    [rtTime] => 20:46:00
                                                    [rtDate] => 2024-08-13
                                                    [hasMainMast] => 1
                                                    [mainMastId] => A=1@O=Rådhuset (på Scheeleg) (Stockholm)@X=18044245@Y=59331035@U=74@L=300101213@
                                                    [mainMastExtId] => 300101213
                                                    [additional] => 
                                                )

                                            [Destination] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [name] => Odenplan
                                                    [type] => ST
                                                    [id] => A=1@O=Odenplan@X=18047993@Y=59342990@U=74@L=400110345@
                                                    [extId] => 400110345
                                                    [lon] => 18.047993
                                                    [lat] => 59.34299
                                                    [prognosisType] => PROGNOSED
                                                    [time] => 20:53:00
                                                    [date] => 2024-08-13
                                                    [track] => A
                                                    [rtTime] => 20:53:00
                                                    [rtDate] => 2024-08-13
                                                    [hasMainMast] => 1
                                                    [mainMastId] => A=1@O=Stockholm Odenplan (Stockholm)@X=18045683@Y=59343116@U=74@L=300101079@
                                                    [mainMastExtId] => 300101079
                                                    [additional] => 
                                                )

PHP code:
$file is the json file I am fetching.
$jsonData = file_get_contents($file);
$data = json_decode($jsonData, true);
       
foreach ($data['Trip'] as $tripData) {
    echo "Name: ".$tripData['Leglist']['Leg']['Origin']['name']; //I don't know what I am doing
    echo "<br><br>";
}

I'm expecting to see "Name: Rådhuset" (origin) or "Name: Odenplan" (destination).

Try $tripData['Leglist']['Leg'][0]['Origin']['name']. You missed the array that's in between Leg and Origin: [Leg] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [Origin]

Thank you, I have already tried that, no luck!

Well what does that mean exactly? Do you get any kind of error message or warning when you try it? Normally if you're accessing the wrong bit of an array which doesn't exist, you'll get a message about it.

It meant that I wrote "['Leglist']" when it should have been "['LegList']". :D

Ah yes, case sensitivity. Sorry I didn't spot that. Glad you fixed it!
